# How can I inject azure credentials from a linux host into a Docker container?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I have an Ubuntu VM in Azure, and I can use `az login ...` to authenticate as a Service Principal/Managed Identity/etc.

How can I propagate those credentials into a Docker container running on that VM?

I have tried mounting `$HOME/.azure` into the container (eg `docker run -v $HOME/.azure:/root/.azure ...`), but this doesn't work.

You might ask: Why not perform the `az login ...` inside the container? The reason I can't do this, is because the `az login` on the VM is performed by an Azure DevOps Pipeline task, using a Service Connection, and I don't have access to the secrets that it sends to `az login`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a [`AzureCLI@2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-cli-v2?view=azure-pipelines) task to your pipeline with the `addSpnToEnvironment` input set to `true` then you'll be able to access the service principal ID, service principal key (secret), and tenant ID in the script as `$servicePrincipalId`, `$servicePrincipalKey` and `$tenantId` variables.  You can invoke Docker in this task and pass them in, and then do an `az login --service-principal ...` in the container.

Comment: Thanks, that's *exactly* the answer I was looking for

Comment: Good stuff :).  Please accept the answer if it helped.